# All wireless devices connected to home wifi network but not connecting to internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I am NOT a network guy by any stretch of the imagination.

Two nights ago, I discovered that all devices that connect to my wifi network at home would not load web content. These devices include a Windows laptop, a Macbook Pro, 2 Leap Frog tablets, 3 iPhones, and a Playstation 3.

I have run ping tests (www.google.com; 8.8.8.8, www.yahoo.com, etc.) on both laptop machines with success. I have restarted and reset the router on multiple occasions with no success. I have googled this issue but not coming across much where anybody has run into the same thing where all devices are experiencing the same thing.

Bad router is at the top of my list of suspicions because we have had it about 2 years. Recently began streaming most of our TV and video so not sure if that pushed the router to the brink of collapse. Up until 2 days ago, the speeds were great.

Is there a definitive test or set of tests to confirm that this is or is not a router that has died. Not that I mind purchasing a new router, but if that's still not the issue that won't be a solution. Like I said, all devices are successfully connected to the wifi network.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can ping external servers, such as 8.8.8.8 it sounds like it could be a DNS issue (as you have replys to external IP's via ping), can you see if port 53 is being blocked, or try connecting to 8.8.8.8 on port 53 via telnet? OR your ISP's DNS server has died, try manually changing the DNS server in your windows network settings to use 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4

Comment: if you can borrow another router that is known to work, you can see if  you have the same problems, regardless of router. Good luck.